# How to programmatically list all properties defined while executing MSBuild?

Tags: list, msbuild, properties, build, defined

I'm looking for a way to access all the Build properties defined while executing MSBuild. I have a configuration file. I want to modify the Properties in the configuration file and copy it to a new location. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about MSBuild $(prop) properties or elements within your custom XML configuration file?

Answer (score 6):

If you run the build with /verbosity:detailed or /verbosity:diagnostic you will get very detailed output of all the properties that was used during your build process.  However I suspect you want to change a config type file after/before you copy the builded files to another location?  In that case there is several mechanismes to do that, what we have found to work pretty good, is the MSBuildCommunity tasks that can be found [here on code plex](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com)

If you would like to see some samples of this I would be glad to post them